# Sql Server Read text file with varying numbers of fields

Tags: c#, sql-server

How can I read variable width records into Sql Server? In my delimted text file, each record can have a varying number of fields - there are 20 core fields, and then a repeating set of extra fields. So a record will have a minimum of 20 fields but could have 200 fields. There isn't a row of FieldNames at the start of the file.

This is a daily process, and we're not having issues with record sizes.

I'm currently using Bash to add a row 0 with unique field names, and I then pad out each record to have the right number of delimiters, ie I create a heap of dummy empty fields. I then read that file as normal into Sql Server using my own application.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: I've ediited the question to make it closer to SO norms

Comment: If you literally called them Field001 Field002 ..  Field199  You could split each record into 4 tables.  Table050  Table100 (fields 51-100)  Table150 Table200.    If you break the really wide 200 fields into smaller tables you will have a higher chance of avoiding a 4000 char or 8000 byte limit that can get you.   Use bash to add a first field with a row number to give you sanity.   You should mention if this is a one off job or a process that is like code.

Comment: @SqlSurfer - we don't have an issue with record sizes. And yes you're answer is correct and works, but is there a native/better way of solving this. The use of Bash, is an issue here as there's not much Unix experience and as a windows dev shop it's not a natural fit

Comment: A proven pattern is to import the row into _one_ large varchar field using standard import tools (i.e. BCP, BULK INSERT, SSIS) then selectively shred it within SQL Server using T-SQL string functions. If you have hundreds of thousands of records this may not scale well. The crux of the problem is that you don't want to shred in Bash. There are many other Windows friendly options such as Powershell and C#. However these are external to SQL Server, which is why I first prefer a T-SQL solution